# AsfMojo - asp.net MVC / Extract Frame from WMV C# Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wmv

I am using AsfMojo (in a handler) in my MVC application to extract a bmp from WMV file, it works great on my localhost IIS7, however the image does not show when I publish the application to our hosting service.

the view script:

```
 <img id="Image1" alt="image"  src="ImageHandler.ashx?img=CT0001.wmv" height="512" width="512" />
```

The handler script:

```
       string videoname = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Video/" + sImageFileName);
            if(File.Exists(videoname)) 
                {
                Bitmap bmp = AsfImage.FromFile(videoname).AtOffset(timeOffset);
                bmp.Save(objMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] imageContent = new byte[objMemoryStream.Length];
                objMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                objMemoryStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)objMemoryStream.Length);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
                context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
                context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Here is the error message when I tried to display the image in a new window using Chrome:

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: image]
   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height) +1133063
   DirectshowTest.ImageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in E:\..\projects\DirectshowTest\DirectshowTest\ImageHandler.ashx.cs:40
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I suspect becasue of the size of the wmv file, the handler script does not wait until it reads all frames in the file in this line:

```
 Bitmap bmp = AsfImage.FromFile(videoname).AtOffset(timeOffset);
```

I tried to cache the contnet response without any luck.  Is there a way to check if the file has completely read before generating the image.

I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? maybe try putting in a File.Exists condition check.

Comment: I added File.Exists, still same error.  I suspect it could be buffering the .wmv file.

Comment: Can you check that all required files are published? Does it work if you publish it in your local iis? Sometime I forget to configure correctly the website and some files are not published.

Comment: I tried two ways, published directly from VS2010, and published to my local storage and then ftp to the hosting server.  The only difference between the two servers is the hosting is a shared hosting, would that make a difference?  thanks

Comment: Which line is that exception being thrown on? We are missing a stack frame in the trace - it goes from DirectshowTest.ImageHandler.ProcessRequest right to System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage, which you don't call directly. If you are publishing a release build, try it with a debug build.

Comment: Also, this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but if everything is the same between your local files and the server files, probably the only difference is that the host will have defaulted its folder permissions not to allow writes from your application. Give your app write access to the Video folder and try again - AsfMojo might "expect" that it has write access to the file and might be trying to open it as such. If that works, I would post an issue on the project page suggesting it support opening files as read only.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I didn't know that I could publish a debug build, I have already tried the permission issue, I made the directory read and write without luck.  The other point could be the process to convert the image does not wait for to read the complete file stream.  I have no clue how to do that.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: "the handler script does not wait until it reads all frames in the file in this line" - not sure what you mean - the bitmap should be completely independent of the video file after this line of code executes - are you doing a `null` check?