# Windows Media Player - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, media-player, wmv

Hi my application is MVC, have a view with windows media player, it plays on my local host but not on the hosting server, MIME is set up correct.
Here is my script:

```
<object codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" 
        classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" 
        type="application/x-oleobject"> 
        <param name="url" value="../../Video/1.wmv"/> 
        <embed src="../../Video/1.wmv" 
            type="application/x-mplayer2" 
            pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed> 
    </object>
```

I tried same script in a simple HTML file, it worked well on the server.

I get 500 Internal Server Error (shown in Fiddler).  Any suggestions.

Comment: `value="../../Video/1.wmv"` that could possibly go out of the website's scope.

Comment: I moved the file to the root directory and took ../../Video out, still same error.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a helper:

```
<param name="url" value="@Url.Content("~/Video/1.wmv")" /> 
<embed src="@Url.Content("~/Video/1.wmv")"
```

This will ensure that a correct url to the video file is generated. In this example I suppose that you have a `Video` sub-directory and the file is inside this directory.

As far as the 500 error is concerned, I suppose it is not related to the code snippet you have shown. Try looking at the server's EventLog where unhandled exceptions are traced.

Comment: Thanks Darin, unfortunately did not work. Exception type: NullReferenceException.  I made this project just to test the error with simple player; the original error I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395238/asfmojo-asp-net-mvc-image-does-not-show-when-published-to-server

Comment: It seems that there's a problem with your server side code. Completely unrelated with the example you have shown here.

Comment: You are right Darin, I built a new project and it worked well, thanks.